# Why are my Google Analytics Page Timings all 0.00%?

Tags: google-analytics

Why are my Google Analytics Page Timings all 0.00%?

Is doing something like this enough to get page timings or is there something different I should be doing?

```
/* GOOGLE ANALYTICS ID */
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', [myid], 'auto');
```

Other stats are working using same ga which I set to my account ID.

Comment: This should be enough, as GA is sending timing hits automatically. Where did you place that code ? I guess if you create the tracker in the page footer then it would be instantiated only after the page has already loaded and thus record zero seconds as load time.

Comment: I have some code in the javascript to decide which GA account to send hits to, and then I include the javascript file to run that code at the top of my html files. Does that make sense or do I just need to have a copy of the Google Analytics code in each html file?

Comment: If I put the (function....'ga') at the top, can I use the ga variable in any file?

Comment: I'd say you should place the part that loads the code at the top (you can see that the start value for the timer is created there : i[r].l=1*new Date(); ) and then it shouldn't matter much where you call the ga function.

Comment: I'm pretty new to JS and GA. How does the ga function get created? When I try to use it in a separate/common file where I can factor out my code for sending different hits to GA it says ga is not a function but I figured it will be a global variable since not using "var". Is the variable only local to this file and if so how can I factor my code to not duplicate the creation code?

Answer (score 2):

That's because of bounce rate.

When a visitor comes to your site, he or she gets a timestamp. So, Analytics might note that User landed on your Homepage at 17:35:03. Then, Analytics assigns a new timestamp when that user accesses a new page on your site. So if user clicks on a link to your About page at 17:36:04, that leaves your Homepage with a Time on Page of 00:01:01.

But what happens if user never accesses another page on your site (in other words, if bounces?

Then there's no second timestamp for Google to work from. So they assign a Time on Page of 00:00:00.

There are few workarounds.

One is explained here: [tracking adjusted bounce rate.](http://analytics.blogspot.hr/2012/07/tracking-adjusted-bounce-rate-in-google.html)

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is related to bounce rate. I'm looking at Page Timings for loading the page. I think the issue was I didn't have a large enough number of samples.

Comment: Behavior->Site Speed->Page Timings

Comment: I know about that. But about the samples? What do you mean by that

Answer (score 2):

I am struggling with this issue as well.  After researching the page tracking site timings, it appears there could be a few issues causing the timings not be recorded:

[GA Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en&utm_id=ad&topic=1282106&visit_id=1-636397885408521762-1610862896&rd=1)

> If you see Help in the PageSpeed Suggestions column, this indicates that we were unable to analyze the page at the given URL, and you should try again later. If the error persists, it may be due to any of the following:
>
> ```
> -The hostname you have configured in the Website’s URL section of your View Settings is not a valid hostname for your website.
> -The URLs shown in the Site Speed Suggestions report are not valid URLs for your website.
> -You are tracking multiple subdomains and not using a single hostname.
> -You have set up view filters to rewrite your URLs.
> -The page requires authentication.
> ```

Most concerning to me is the "page requires authentication" item.  I think that will prevent me from collecting this data.